# Show a form with a list of questions to answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a collection with predefined questions and a user whom should answer all these questions. So the view should be something like:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  -#some code and then...
    %table.table
      - @questions.each do |q|
        %tr
          %td=q.name
          %td
            %input-# Here the answer of the user for the question 'q'
```

So the view should show too each of the user answers for each question. My problem is that in first instance there shouldn't be any answer, so I couldn't use something like:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  -#some code and then...
    %table.table
      - @user.answers.each do |answer|
        = f.fields_for :answers, answer do |a|
          %tr
            %td= answer.question.name
            %td=a.number_field :result
```

In this case there won't be any answers so nothing will show. Even if there would be an answer I must to show all the questions to the user. I could just pre-initialize the answers with empty values, but I don't want to have a bunch of records just with empty values(most of these questions maybe never will be answered by the user). Another thing is that the questions has an order and I don't know how is gonna be sorted with the `@user.answers.each` loop (yeah, I could modify the query, so it could be sorted, but I would be tweaking too much for something...simple?). In general the main loop should be `@questions.each` and not `@user.answers.each`.

I've been thinking in some nasty ways to do that, like creating the fields manually, several if/else conditions, but I'm hoping that rails has a clean way to do that. Somebody has crossed with a problem like this before? There's no other way to do that but create all of these with custom helpers?. Thanks in advance

**Update**

At the end, thanks to @saverio answer, I left it as follows:

```
%table.table
  - @questions.each_with_index do |q, i|
    %tr
      %td= q.name
      %td
        - answer = @user.answers.detect{|a| a.question.try(:id) == q.id}
        = number_field_tag "user[answers_attributes][#{i}][result]", (answer && answer.result)
        = hidden_field_tag "user[answers_attributes][#{i}][id]", (answer && answer.id)
        = hidden_field_tag "user[answers_attributes][#{i}][question_id]", q.id
```

In the controller, with the next line, was enough to clean all the empty values:

```
params[:user][:answers_attributes].delete_if{|k,v| v[:result].blank? && v[:id].blank?}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over @questions, and at each step show a field for the corresponding answer. If an answer has been provided, show it as preloaded text

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  -#some code and then...
    %table.table
      - @questions.each do |q|
        - answer = @user.answers.detect {|a| a.question.name == q}
        %tr
          %td= q.name
          %td= text_field_tag "user[answers][#{q.id}]", (answer && answer.text)
```

In the controller you'll have to parse the `params[:user][:answers]`, which will be a hash from the question's ID to the provided answer.